# Virtual Keyboard Numpad with 'Enter' key in Windows UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox, soft-keyboard

When creating a TextBox in XAML i can choose between various virtual keyboards (property InputScope). I just need a Numpad to specify a quantity. Now i have the problem that none of the number keyboards has an Enter-Key. But the default alphanumeric keyboard is not very handy if you just want to enter numbers. Does somebody know how to pop up a virtual Numpad including an Enter-Key?

Comment: sadly no, you cannot edit virtual keyboards.

Comment: That's a shame. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As touseefbsb already said there doesn't seem to be a virtual Numpad including an Enter-Key at the moment.